# PHP＋MYSQLでpvのカウント

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

現在以下のようにプログラムを組んでいますが、一度ページをリロードすると、列が2つ増えてしまいます。これは何故でしょうか？
詳しい方、ご教示下さい。よろしくお願いいたします。

テーブルの構造は以下になっています。

- id
- page_id
- ip
- created

以下はソースコードの一部です。

```php
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pv_counts WHERE ip =" . $ip .
        " AND created > current_timestamp - interval 30 minute";
$within_threeminutes = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
$within_threeminutes->execute();
$within_threeminutes_count = $within_threeminutes->fetch();

if($within_threeminutes_count == false){
  $sql = "insert into `pv_counts` 
            (`page_id`, `ip`, `created`) 
          values 
            (:page_id, :ip, now())";
  $insert_pv = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $params = array(
    ":page_id" => "index",
    ":ip" => $ip
  );
  $insert_pv->execute($params);
}
```

追記：やりたい事としましては、30分以内に同じipでのアクセスがないかを確認して、無い場合はdbにinsertするといったものです。

データベースをみると、10.0.1.206,10.0.0.208といった自分のipではないものが増えています。
サーバーはAWSを使用しています。

var_dump($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
の実行結果が自分のipアドレスではなく、上記の10.0.0.208になっています。

Comment: リロードしたタイミングでのアクセスログはどうなっていますか。あと、増えるのはカラムではなくて列ということでよいですか。

Comment: 問題の原因とは関係のないことでしょうけれども、`ip` はおそらく文字列でしょうから、SQL の SELECT 文は `... WHERE ip ='" . $ip . "' AND ...` の様にシングルクォートで囲むべきではないかと思います。

Comment: argusさんのコメントが正解ではないでしょうか。$sql2をプリペアしたexecute（）はエラー処理していないのでこのプログラムはいつも行を挿入する動作をするように見えます。プリペアしているならipをプレースホルダに入れるといいのではないでしょうか。なぜ、4行追加されるのはこの中にはないもの（他のコンポーネントのロードなど）が原因でしょう。

Comment: >リロードしたタイミングでのアクセスログはどうなっていますか。あと、増えるのはカラムではなくて列ということでよいですか。
申し訳ありません。列で合っています。
現在確認してみたところ、interval 30 minute"の部分はを5 secondに変えてみると、リロードをしていないのに、5秒ごとに列が増えていきます。
そして、何故か、二種類のipが交互に増えていきます。。。
何が起こっているのでしょうか？

Comment: argusさん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正致しました。

Comment: こちらの質問は解決済みでしょうか？（過去の質問もそうですが）もし解決しているのであれば、いずれかの回答の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックして、解決済みのマークを付けていただけないでしょうか？ 参考 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> データベースをみると、10.0.1.206,10.0.0.208といった自分のipではないものが増えています。
>   サーバーはAWSを使用しています。

IPの範囲がプライベートIP ということから推測しますと、AWS VPC 内の別の EC2 インスタンスもしくは ELB ヘルスチェックの送信元 IP だと思います。

ELB ヘルスチェック によるアクセスの場合、User-Agent が `ELB-HealthChecker/1.0` のような値になっていると思います。

また、Amazon Route53 のヘルスチェックを使っている場合は User-Agent が `Amazon Route 53 Health Check Service` のような値になります。

これらは監視用に定期的にアクセスが来ますので pv の集計から除外すればよろしいかと思います。

仮に 送信元が別のEC2インスタンスの場合は、インスタンスのプライベートIPから送信元を割り出して、何をしているか調査されるといいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

まずは`var_dump()` やファイル出力(`file_put_contents()` など)を用いてデバッグするのが良いかと思います。

insertする直前に`var_dump()` や`file_put_contents()`などを記載して何回出力されたかを確認して
・複数回出力された場合：insert部分が回数分呼び出されている
・1回のみ出力された場合：insert部分の呼び出しは1回のみ
ということがわかるのでデバッグできるようになるかと思います。
※file_put_contentsを使うときは追記モードにて使用してください。

追記：
外部からのアクセスがある可能性があるので、まず自分のみアクセス出来る状況を作って試してみてください。
例えば、ベーシック認証をかけてしまうのもアリかと思います。

Comment: var_dumpを試してみましたが出力は一度だけでした。
どのような原因が考えれますでしょうか。
お手数ですが、回答頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 修正された質問内容を見ましたが、これは単純に複数回ロードされているのではないでしょうか？
外部からのアクセスがある可能性はありますか？
botなどのアクセスが来ていないかどうか、アクセスログと付きあわせてみるといいと思います

Comment: 追記にも記しましたが、var_dump($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
の実行結果が自分のipアドレスではなく、10.0.0.208になっています。
これはどのような原因が考えられますでしょうか。

Comment: http://www.ugtop.com/spill.shtml
このサイトの赤文字のところに自分のIPが出ますが、こちらを確認するとIPはいくつでしょうか？